# Ошибка! Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Доброго времени суток, не могу понять, почему не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста)
Раньше всё получалось, сейчас...Увы, что я делаю не так?
Заранее спасибо)

JS:

```
 let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('.btnView');

btn[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('asda');
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>STO</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="cont">
            <div class="setting">
                <h1>Настройки</h1>
                <hr>
                <div class="wheels">

                    <h3>Выберите тип колёс:</h3>
                    <div class="wheels-choose"> 
                        <div class="default-wheels"><img src="def wheel.png" alt=""> <button onclick="redwheels.style.display = 'none'" id="btn-def">Обычные</button i></div>
                        <div class="default-wheels"><img src="prev red wheel.png" alt=""> <button onclick="redwheels.style.display = 'block'" id="btn-red"> Красные</button></div>   
                </div>
                <div class="tinting">
                    <h3>Выберите тонировку:</h3>
                    <div class="tinting-choose">
                    <div class="black-tinting"><img src="def tinting.png" alt=""><button onclick="blacktinting.style.display = 'none'"  id="btn-notting">Без тонировки</button onclick="redwheels.style.display = 'block'"></div>                    
                    <div class="black-tinting"><img src="black tinting.png" alt=""><button onclick="blacktinting.style.display = 'block'" id="btn-blackting">Чёрная тонировка</button></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="color">
                    <h3>Выберите цвет:</h3>
                    <div class="color-choose">
                        <div class="red-color"><img src="depositphotos_105327192-stock-photo-opel-astra-isolated-on-white.png" alt=""><button onclick="redauto.style.display = 'none'" id="btn-graycolor" >Серый</button></div>
                        <div class="red-color"><img src="red-auto.png" alt=""><button onclick="redauto.style.display = 'block'" id="btn-redcolor">Красный</button></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="auto">
                <div class="output">
                    <img id="defaultauto" src="depositphotos_105327192-stock-photo-opel-astra-isolated-on-white.png" alt="">
                    <img id="blacktinting" src="3.png" alt="">
                    <img id="redwheels" src="red wheels.png" alt="">
                    <img id="redauto" src="red-auto.png" alt="">
                    <img id="leftView" src="left.png" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="view">
                    <button onclick="leftView.style.display = 'block'; defaultauto.style.display = 'none';" class="btnView">Вид с левого бока</button>
                    <button class="btnView">Вид с правого бока</button>
                    <button class="btnView">Вид спереди</button class="btnView">
                    <button class="btnView">Вид сзади</button>
                </div>
            </div>




  </div>



  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: у Вас там в закрывающем теге есть параметр,  в html так не принято

Comment: Я бы вообще проверял, что хоть что-то в коллекцию нашлось по селектору.

Comment: @bonusrk, видимо проще на StackOverflow написать, нежели console.log() прописать )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это я дурацкий, подключил в head, нужно было в body. Исправил, всё работает

Answer (score 3):

```
    let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btnView');/*точка лишняя*/

btn[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('asda');
});
```